# Quick Question - ContourPlot a Rectangular region

Tags: plotting, scaling

I have been using the contourplot command to illustrate the eigenfunctions of a 2x1 rectangle. However, the contourplot scales the y axis to make the region square, which is distorting the image.

The command I have used to plot my eigenfunctions is:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[evIF[[15]][x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None, ImageSize -> 500, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

Which produces:

[image: Square Region]

However, the region is a 2x1 rectangle, so the plot should actually look like this:
[image: Unscaled Version]

Is there any additional command I can use to prevent the scaling from happening? I am new to mathematica and am still trying to pick up the basics.

Comment: Add the option `AspectRatio - > 1/2` (or `AspectRatio -> 2`, I can't remember which is which).

Comment: `Automatic` will keep the same scale for x and y.

Comment: Excellent march! That has certainly done the trick. I'll have to note that command down for future instances. Thank you very much. The automatic command seems very useful  but I keep getting an error. Is the automatic command supposed to be added as an option?

Comment: @MrS100 yep, sorry I mean `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.

Comment: Thanks Kuba - that's sorted it now. Thanks for the help! I apologise if this is similar to another post. I did some searches about changing the scale of a contour plot but couldn't find anything.